# How to use `electron` based app update file which requires `sudo` permission

Tags: sudo, electron

I want to write an app via `electron`, but the requirement is to update a file which requires `root` permission.

It's easy to achieve via `cli`, just like `sudo vi xxx`.

Is it possible to update the file via `electron`?

Comment: Take a look on this: https://github.com/automation-stack/electron-sudo. Provides a native OS dialog prompt that you can use from Electron.

Comment: It's weird, i tried it in debug mode, works fine. But once packaged, not working at all. So i switched to `sudo-prompt`. Thanks any way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible via `electron`.

You can use https://github.com/jorangreef/sudo-prompt to `exec` a command using `sudo` and show a graphical OS password prompt.

You can use `sudo-prompt` from Electron as well as from any Node script.

It is regularly updated, has no dependencies and does not require any native compilation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Only one deficiency, it has no `windows` support

Comment: It has support for `Windows` as of today.

Comment: @JoranGreef I am not able to use sudo-prompt in ubuntu as electron app is running in it's own sandbox and the error says **pkexec must be setuid root**. It's not able to find the pkexec i guess. So you have any workaround for that?

Comment: @SimarSingh, this is an Electron issue, the Electron team have a fix for this, please see: https://github.com/jorangreef/sudo-prompt/issues/100

Comment: Thank you soooo much! Spent a whole bunch of time trying to make electron-sudo work, but it just didn't :( this alternative worked by 2 lines of code